# Qt round rectangle, why corners are different?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, rasterizing

I try to draw a round rectangle with `drawRoundedRect` method directly in a `QPixmap` (no render engine involve here exept pure Qt one ...), I double check the size of the rectangle versus the size of my pixmap :

```
Pixmap : QSize(50, 73) 
Rectangle: QRect(0,0 48x11)
```

See plenty of space ...

EDIT: some code

```
pixmap = QPixmap(50,73); //example size that match my case
QRectF rect(0,0,48,11);

QPainter painter(&pixmap);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
painter.setWorldMatrixEnabled(false);
painter.setPen(QPen()); //no pen
painter.setBrush(QBrush(color));
painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, 2.0, 2.0);
```

- I disabled world transformation ...
- I set set transformation to unity ...
- I tried several radius (1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0) ...
- I change pen width, brush color ...

But it always ends with a rectamgle with 4 diferent corners ! Like that :

[image: Radius = 3.0 in x and y]

I directly ouptut the pixmap to a file to be sure I wasn't scraping it during the display ... same shape.

Anyone know about Qt round rectangle with small radius ? I saw somthing about it a long time ago but I don't remenber how to deal with it !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you're not using anti-aliasing (i.e. the `QPainter::Antialiasing` render hint).  This is a Qt quirk that occurs without it.  From what I've seen/heard, the Qt devs aren't terribly concerned with fixing this (most people want anti-aliasing anyway).

The work-around (besides just using anti-aliasing) is to draw the rect yourself with `QPainter::drawLine()` and `QPainter::drawArc()`.  You might have to play with numbers until it looks right -- straight calculations tend to come out a pixel or two off.  Also, you might find that even with this method the lower right corner is never *exactly* the same as the other corners.

If you're feeling mildly ambitious, you could try fixing this and submitting a patch to Qt.

**Update:** Arc drawing results changed in Qt 5. In my experience, it's a big improvement.

Comment: I played with antialising other way to draw stuff (drwa path, arc ...). Antialiasing with such small stuff make it worth ! And my best shot was addind ~0.5 every where quessing where rouding can produce weird behavior ... So I will accept the **play with numbers** method !

Comment: Had the same problem. Using `QPainter p(this); p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing); p.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old problem but for `Qt5` users calling `setRenderHint(QPainter::Qt4CompatiblePainting);` on the `QPainter` seems to solve the problem.

**Edit:**

I found a solution for generating a perfect rounded rectangle together with border color and it looks the same as the rounded rectangles used by `QPushButton`'s border for example. This is how I implemented the `paintEvent` to achieve this:

```
void MyButtonGroup::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
    int borderSize = 5;
    QColor borderColor = Qt::red;
    QColor backgroundColor = Qt::blue;
    int borderRadius = 3;

    QPen pen;
    pen.setWidth(borderSize);
    pen.setColor(borderColor);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setPen(pen);

    QRectF rect(rect().x() + borderSize / 2,
                rect().y() + borderSize / 2,
                rect().width() - borderSize,
                rect().height() - borderSize);


    if(borderSize % 2 == 0)
    {
        painter.drawRoundedRect(rect,
                                borderSize,
                                borderSize);
    }
    else
    {
        painter.drawRoundedRect(rect.translated(0.5, 0.5),
                                borderRadius,
                                borderRadius);
    }

    QBrush brush(backgroundColor);
    pen.setBrush(brush);
    painter.setBrush(brush);

    if(borderSize % 2 == 0)
    {
        painter.drawRoundedRect(rect,
                                borderRadius,
                                borderRadius);
    }
    else
    {
        painter.drawRoundedRect(rect.translated(0.5, 0.5),
                                borderRadius,
                                borderRadius);
    }

    QWidget::paintEvent(e);
}
```

I'm posting this because I found it a bit hard to achieve this result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try adding half a pixel offset (e.g.: `rect.translated(0.5,0.5)` ):

```
QRectF rect(0,0,48,11);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,false);
painter.drawRoundedRect( rect.translated(0.5,0.5), 2.0, 2.0 );
```

I suppose this has to do with the coordinate system placing an integer value *between* two pixels.

If you draw with antialiasing and use a pen of 1 pixel width then drawing at exact integer coordinates results in lines of 2 pixel width instead. 
Only with this 0.5 pixel offset you'll get lines that are exactly 1 pixel wide.

```
QRectF rect(0,0,48,11);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true);
painter.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
painter.setPen( Qt::white );
painter.drawRoundedRect( rect.translated(0.5,0.5), 2.0,2.0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way do draw RoundRect is Path.
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Qt_rounded_rect_widget

```
void fillRoundRect(QPainter& painter, QRect r, int radius)
{
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true);

    QPainterPath rounded_rect;
    rounded_rect.addRoundRect(r, radius, radius);
    painter.setClipPath(rounded_rect);

    painter.fillPath(rounded_rect,painter.brush());     
    painter.drawPath(rounded_rect);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to play with render hints
1) disable antiAliasing;
2) enable SmoothPixmapTransform

but still no guarantee that it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all tips from answers here but nothing works for me. But based on these code snippets I have found following solution:

As default set `m_pPainter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Qt4CompatiblePainting, true)` and only for rounded rectangles with width%2==0 disable it.

```
QRect rect = ConvertRectangle(rectangle);

int nPenWidth = m_pPainter->pen().width();
if ( nPenWidth % 2 == 0 )
    m_pPainter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Qt4CompatiblePainting, false);

m_pPainter->drawRoundedRect(rect, dbRadiusX, dbRadiusY);

if ( nPenWidth % 2 == 0 )
    m_pPainter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Qt4CompatiblePainting, true);
```